# Why is RIOSend slower than classic winapi socket send?

Tags: sockets, winapi, tcp, winsock, tcpclient

I am testing two apps with TCP sockets. First app uses new RIO socket calls, the second app uses classic Winsock socket calls. Both apps send a single string to a server. I made them both use non-blocking sockets and disabled the Nagle algorithm. When I measure the time it takes to execute the sends, contrary to my expectations the classic socket is faster.  What is the reason for this?

Here is my code:

```c
/* 
  Classic socket
*/
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

// ... socket initialization

// Make socket non-blocking and disable Nagle's algorithm
unsigned long mode = 1;
ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
int isOn = 1;
setsockopt(ConnectSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &isOn, sizeof(int) );

// Measure exec time
t1 = __rdtscp(&dum);
iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
t2 = __rdtscp(&dum);
cout << (t2 - t1) / 3000.0f << " 10^-6 sec" << endl;

/* 
  RIO socket
*/
SOCKET s = WSASocket(
        AF_INET,
        SOCK_STREAM,
        IPPROTO_TCP,
        NULL,
        0,
        WSA_FLAG_REGISTERED_IO);

// ... socket initialization

// Make socket non-blocking and disable Nagel's algorithm
unsigned long mode = 1;
ioctlsocket(s, FIONBIO, &mode);
int isOn = 1;
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&isOn, sizeof(int));

// RIO socket is event-based
hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
RIO_NOTIFICATION_COMPLETION type;
type.Type = RIO_EVENT_COMPLETION;
type.Event.EventHandle = hEvent;
type.Event.NotifyReset = TRUE;
RIO_CQ complQueue = rioFuncTable.RIOCreateCompletionQueue(1000, &type);

RIO_RQ requestQueue = rioFuncTable.RIOCreateRequestQueue(
        s,
        10,
        1,
        10,
        1,
        complQueue,
        complQueue,
        NULL);

// Init rio buffers
char *pSndBuffer = new char[sndBufferSize + 1]();
std::copy(message, message + sndBufferSize, pSndBuffer); // put message to a server here

RIO_BUFFERID sndBufID = rioFuncTable.RIORegisterBuffer(pSndBuffer, sndBufferSize);
RIO_BUF sndBuffer;
sndBuffer.BufferId = sndBufID;
sndBuffer.Offset = 0;
sndBuffer.Length = sndBufferSize;

// Measure exec time
t1 = __rdtscp(&dum);
rioFuncTable.RIOSend(requestQueue, &sndBuffer, 1, 0, NULL);
t2 = __rdtscp(&dum);
cout << (t2 - t1) / 3000.0f << " 10^-6 sec" << endl;
```

Comment: Are you sure `send()` and `RIOSend()` are actually succeeding?  You are not checking their return values for errors, and not outputting the values to the console. Since the sockets are in non-blocking mode, `send()` and `RIOSend()` can send fewer bytes than you ask them to send.  Maybe `send()` is "faster" because it is sending fewer bytes than `RIOSend()` is sending. You are not even waiting for `RIOSend()`'s completion event to be signaled before retrieving the elapsed time. I don't see you calling `RIONotify()` or `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()`.

Comment: For that matter, what makes you think RIO will be faster anyway?  When sending small amounts of data, the performance will likely be comparable to each other. It is when you start sending lots of data over a longer period of time that RIO will likely outperform classic.  But even then, MSDN says that RIO is "*targeted **primarily for server applications**,*" so clients might not see as big a gain as you are expecting.

Comment: Both apps send strings to a server successfully. I am waiting for RIOSend's completion, I just omitted the code which is not related to sockets' creation, because what I am interested in is the speed of RIOSend by itself.
My client app is going to send requests extensively, so I am still considering RIO. Are you suggesting to test exec time not of a single send request, but of a large amount of different requests?

Comment: I'm saying that you are using `send()` and `RIOSend()` asynchronously, so all they are really doing is submitting data into a kernel buffer and then exiting immediately, the actual transmission is handled in the background while your app has already moved on to other things. So it is not really a fair test to clock the time it takes individual sends to be submitted to the kernel buffer.  So yes, clock a bunch of sends over a longer period of time, that will give you a better idea of whether RIO is really helping or not.

Answer (score 0):

RioSend() sends for real. send() memcopies the buffer to socket's tx buffer.

Comment: In this case. [`RioSend()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has various possible behaviours in general.

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, with Nagle disabled, with no _DEFER flag, RioSend() would go to the nic and initiate the DMA.